# programmatically set the displayed date for a dijit.calendar

Tags: javascript, dojo

By default the dijit.calendar shows the current date / month.  Using the visual controls a user can change the view and choose a date.  I need to problematically change the displayed date based on other circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `set` the `value` property, similarly to other widgets

```
//change the calendar's date to just now:
myCalendar.set('value', new Date() )

//change the calendar's date to Christmas eve
myCalendar.set('value', new Date(2012, 11, 24) )
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I have `<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Calendar" id="myCal"><script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onChange" data-dojo-args="value">-some onChange event--</script></div>` and I `dijit.byId('myCal').set('value', new Date());`

Comment: @SathishKumarkk: You should ask this as a separate question. Noone else is going to see your post if its just a comment under my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who wants to change the "Displayed Date" and not the "Selected Date" of the calendar, you want the `currentFocus` of the calendar.  That is, the selected `value` could be Jan 1, 2012, but the calendar is currently displaying December.

Try

```
// display the month of December 2012
widget.set('currentFocus', Date(2012, 11, 24))
```